# Escape slash in variable for awk pattern

Tags: awk, escape-characters

I want to get all lines within specified date.
The following pattern prints 15/Jan however when used for awk it gives Fatal Unmatched error.

```
pattern=$(date -d "2 day ago" +'%d/%b')
awk '$4 ~ $pattern' file.txt
```

I have tried \ to escape the / sign, so far not successful.

Comment: awk doesn't know about shell variables, and in awk, `$` is completely unrelated *operator*. `$pattern` is actually `$0` and will try to get the whole line. Try with `awk -v "pattern=$pattern" '$4 ~ pattern' file.txt` instead.

Comment: Thank you Uncle Billy. This solved